# Find the value of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$

s.t. 
$$f(x+n) > f(x) \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N$$
$$f(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$$
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f(x)\in \mathcal C^0 \ \ \ f(x) \ \text{is continuous}$$

The question is, $f(1)=?$

Comment: It is too beginnerish in the sense that you behave like a first-day user, when you've been around long enough to have learned not to ask bare problem statement questions, without any context.  Start acting like someone with 400+ rep!  I'm copying this to respond to any statement like "Sorry if the question is too beginnerish".  If you were a beginner, one might understand the need to explain how the site works, and how to ask a good question.  You're no longer a beginner, so stop behaving like you are.

Comment: the comment above is to your now deleted comment in your post: "Sorry if the question is too beginnerish", the line you've used on more than a dozen posts, and counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function, since $\lim_{x\to n^-} f(x) = f(n-1).$ Since the function is continuous $f(n-1) = f(n),$ which contradicts your first condition.